# What's the default intellisense shortcut in vs2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to open the intelligence window without typing a character and then backspacing it. I can't seem to remember the shortcut for this. What is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>?

Also, go to [Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx) or [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx), you can then search for commands and see what is assigned to that (and remap).

Answer (score 31):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for normal Intellisense, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for parameter Intellisense (e.g. to see what overloads are available in a method call which you've actually already filled in). I find the latter very handy :)

Comment: ctrl-shift-space is great! Thanks! I always hit cancel when the parameters appear and struggle to make them show up again.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed MSG Plus, then the problem is messenger lock keys, try to change them in msg plus and Intellisense will work again. Good Luck!