# Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to display IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the keyboard shortcut for Visual Studio to display the IntelliSense box if one accidentally hits <kbd>ESC</kbd> and wants the box come back again?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145371/whats-the-default-intellisense-shortcut-in-vs2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the default intellisense shortcut in vs2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145371/whats-the-default-intellisense-shortcut-in-vs2008)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

You can also go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Keyboard* and check what is assigned to these shortcuts. The command name should be `Edit.CompleteWord`.

Comment: Of note for Messenger plus! users: You have to *change* the lock shortcut, even if it is disabled it interferes with Visual Studio. `Plus! > Preferences & Options > Features > Messenger lock`, and, `Plus! > Passwords > Unlock Messenger`.

Answer (score 209):

Additionally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> shows you Quick info (handy inside parameters)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows you parameter information.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Space is all I needed, I was kinda tired of removing a single character from a parameter just so I could see all signatures and parameter info. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

The most efficient one is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

It helps to automate insertions of `using` directives. It works if the focus is on a new identifier, e.g. class name.

Comment: Perhaps this should be qualified with C#. Neither VB.NET or C++ has `using`.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should do it.

Answer (score 5):

It should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

If you have arrived at this question because IntelliSense has stopped working properly and you are hoping to *force* it to show you what you need, then most likely none of these solutions are going to work.

Closing and restarting Visual Studio should fix the problem.

Comment: Most of the time, this solution works for me. Bug? But it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change whether it highlights the best fitting possibility, use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> (if Num Lock is disabled) are also possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015 this shortcut opens a preview of the definition which even works through typedefs and #defines.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio Community 7.5.3 on Mac this works for me:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to bring up the IntelliSense box is called `Edit.ListMembers`. It defaults to:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

The shortcut to automatically select the most likely option is `Edit.CompleteWord`. It defaults to:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You have to have your cursor on the code which has a red line under it. Now press :

> Ctrl + K + I