# KeyBoard SHortcut to show the description of an error of mouseover

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I currently use ReSharper with VS2010 - I love the fact that there are keyboard shortcuts for nearly everything - however there is one I just cannot find...

If I have the following code block... and I have a red squigly under the area where there is an error

[image]

If I move my mouse over the red squigly I get the error popup as follows...

[image]

Is there some keyboard shortcut to show this popup dialog with the error message - I would like to avoid using the mouse but still see the error message.

Comment: You could look at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense) post on SO [Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to display intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense)

Comment: Thanks Pieter... Ctrl + Space is for IntelliSense, what I am looking for is the similar, but the error description, not the intellisense prompt

Comment: It's CTRL - K and I from the link.

Comment: @PieterGermishuys Ctrl+K,Ctrl+I is only for method description, not for **error** description.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the **status bar** of Visual Studio when cursor is placed on error. There is the same error message.
Unfortunatly status bar is too small for long error messages. But it's enough for 80% of error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Ctrl + \ + e** to show the **Error List** window. You can see the error there without using mouse.

[image]