# VS 2013 : Keyboard Shortcut to show the description of an error of mouseover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is basically the same question as [KeyBoard SHortcut to show the description of an error of mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310840/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-the-description-of-an-error-of-mouseover) but with regards to Visual Studio 2013 (without Reshaper). The answer in that question, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) no longer seems to work in Visual studio 2013

I am re-asking here:

If I have the following code block... and I have a red squiggly under the area where there is an error

[image: screenshot of vs texteditor]

If I move my mouse over the red squiggly I get the error popup as follows...

[image: screenshot of mouse-over error description]

Is there some keyboard shortcut to show this popup dialog with the error message - I would like to avoid using the mouse but still see the error message.

**Update**: Like I said <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> doesn't seem to be working properly.

Here is what i get when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

[image: ctrl-k,ctrl-i]

Here is what i get when I mouse-over (This is what I went to get)
[image: mouse over]

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the Visual Studio 2013 and <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd> works for me. It's assigned to `Edit.QuickInfo` action in the *Text Editor* and *Workflow Designer* and it displays exactly what mouse-over displays and also what's displayed in the *Status bar* when the text cursor is on an underlined word.

Open the *Tools* menu, *Options...*, *Environment*, *Keyboard* and check what action is assigned to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd>. Just press it in *Press shortcut keys* textbox.

Or the opposite — check what shortcut is assigned to the action `Edit.QuickInfo` (by searching it).

You can configure both to whatever you want.

Also, check if `Edit.QuickInfo` is actually what you want. Open the *Edit* menu, *IntelliSense* submenu and select the *Quick Info* (there should be an assigned shortcut displayed next to the menu item). If it's not what you want, then probably some extension have overridden original mouse-over action and you need to find which action it is.

But as I wrote the default mouse-over action is `Edit.QuickInfo`.

Answer (score -1):

hit`ctrl+\+E`
view the Error List window (default out-of-the-box keyboard config).

Comment: How can you see the mouse-over error hint in the *Error List* window? It contains compilation errors only.