# Auto complete stops working on Node.js projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I have encountered an annoying bug which intellisense doesn't show me code completions whenever I type characters. intellisense will only show code completions when I use the key shortcut `ctrl + space`.

But when I am working on a different type of javascript project, auto completion works fine.

Auto completion doesn't work even though statements completion is enable in:

- Options>Text Editor>All languages>Auto list members + Parameter information
- Options>Text Editor>Javascript>Auto list members + Parameter information
- Options>Text Editor>Node.js>Auto list members + Parameter information

I also tried:

- Reinstalling VS!.
- Reinstalling nodejs tools for vs.
- Restarting vs.
- Reopening the file which I currently working on.
- Working on a new Nodejs project.

I am using VS2013 update 4.

I am using Resharper.

I am using Web Essentials for update 4.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio:

```
Click Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->General
Uncheck "Auto list members"
Uncheck "Parameter information"
Check "Auto list members" (yes, the one you just unchecked)
Check "Parameter information" (again, the one you just unchecked)
Click OK
```

If this doesn't work, here's a few more steps to try:

```
If still not working, close all windows and reopen
If still not working, close/reopen solution
If still not working, restart VS.
```

(I haven't yet figured out why more drastic steps are required in some cases.)

```
Tested in VS 2013
I found this to be much faster than rebooting VS
```

This is more or less stepping through the instructions in the link provided by T Driver.

Logging possible causes:

```
Copy/pasting controls on a page. I found that my designer.vb file didn't update from this, either.
Copy/pasting code from another page that caused an error because the code copied referred to a control that wasn't on the page I was pasting to.
```

(Taken from Tony L.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982526/why-does-intellisense-and-code-suggestion-stop-working-when-visual-studio-is-ope))