# VsCode: How to make intellisense for nodejs modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

```
var http=require('http');
var server=new http.Server(function(req,res){
console.log(req.method,req.url)

});

server.listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');
```

I am very new at nodejs, use VS Code and I like intellisense on it. But I do not know how to enable intellisense on nodejs modules?

For example: if I type `server.` I can not see any functions and properties of this object.
How to enable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto complete stops working on Node.js projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395053/auto-complete-stops-working-on-node-js-projects)

Comment: @try-catch-finally, this question about Visual Studio Code (simple text redactor from Microsoft), not Visual Studio.