# Intellisense not working in Visual studio 2015 Razor templates after changing the Target Framework

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I recently happened to change the `TargetFramework` of my application from `.Net framework 4.5` to `4`. Then after resolving all the errors of unmatched version reference, I started facing new problem in `VS IDE` which is the absence of VS intellisense and this is really annoying. I followed <kbd>**[Link1](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1008)**</kbd>, <kbd>**[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27991492/2065039)**</kbd> and <kbd>**[Link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48807/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio.aspx)**</kbd> and also the <kbd>**[Latest one from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense)**</kbd> etc., where various solutions have been stated but unfortunately none of them worked. Above all, the settings I had previously have been lost now and still the issue exists.

[image: Sample Image]

This issue of intellisense is only for `RazorViews` where as other intellisenses works well and good. Can anyone tell me any workarounds for this or anything I haven't followed to correct this.. At last I will be having only one option.. Uninstall and install it again, which I want to avoid. Does changing the `Target Framework` needs to change anything else too?

Below is my VS details:

> **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL**
>
> **Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079**
>
> **Installed Version: Professional**

---

**Update:**

Also when I hover on controller side `MVC` method, its displaying information in some different characters, may be Chinese, not sure though. Attached an sample image below:

[image]

Is this all because of changing `TargetFramework`?

Comment: Check the web.config file under the Views directory to ensure they reference the correct assembly versions, but based on your update I'm not sure that's the problem

Comment: Alright.. Let me verify that too.. But I doubt, if it was that then it should have given me complie time error, saying versions mismatch, and I have already solved this @Moho..