# Visual Studio Intellisense List is Empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

When I write a code in a certain project, Intellisense window is popping up but the list is empty (it's like the items are invisible) and when I try to click, nothing happens.

[image: Empty Intellisense List]

[image: No suggestions List]

Before I saw that Intellisense window does not pop-up but I have different problem.

So what I did to solve:

1. Checked items from the option window
2. deleted the suo files,
3. reset the user settings
4. restart VS and the machine

I opened another project and it works. But for the certain project it does not. I've googled but not found any similar problem.

The problem just happened.

I am using VS 2015, version 14 Update 2

Comment: Somebody is clashing with your intellisense.. Like maybe a nuget you installed or some package. But strange

Comment: I deleted nuget packages that I installed for a project and restart the VS, still the same.. One time it came but after dissepared

Comment: I think this is a bug that has been around for some time.  Have you seen or tried the things mentioned on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982526/why-does-intellisense-and-code-suggestion-stop-working-when-visual-studio-is-ope

Comment: @Fred, I also followed this page except adding Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extension.dll now i am looking for it..

Comment: and i dont have this dll on my computer :)

Comment: I gave the same project to my friend and he tried it on his computer and it works so i have problem with my visual studio

Comment: You can check what's going wrong in ActivityLog.xml file: `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml` (post related XML log contents in your question if necessary for further analysis). Also, you may use `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` in CMD as **last resort** if any given attempts still won't work.

Comment: @unbalanced ,you can try to run the VS with safe mode using the command: devenv /safemode in the evaluated command prompt, if the intellisense works fine, which means one or some installed extensions affect this issue, you can go to Tools-Extensions and Update-Installed, remove the installed extension one by one to find the culprit. Meanwhile, what’s the project type of this certain project, try to check a new project with the same type to check if this issue will happen or not.

Comment: From your screenshot, I found there have the intellisense filters at the bottom of completion list, your VS is VS 2017, right? Since the intellisense filter is the new feature in VS 2017 RC, we can know it from here:https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/11/29/visual-studio-2017-rc-new-and-improved-features/.

Comment: I am unbalanced and i cant logging this account :) Well I installed windows and VS so now it is fine :) I cant test anymore the problem. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to close your Visual studio completely ?and reset your settings?.Otherwise It should be a bug of VS 2015.