# Intellisense for C# not working in ASP.net project | Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am making an ASP.Net application, but for some reason Intellisense is not working for the C# code. The Code is white and Errors are not shown as well. It is working great for HTML though. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does intellisense and code suggestion stop working when Visual Studio is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982526/why-does-intellisense-and-code-suggestion-stop-working-when-visual-studio-is-ope)

Answer (score 0):

Just close visual studio and open it again and then check..
Open solution and build again because intellisense uses metadata to get property and all other things. There are changes metadata not loaded properly

Or

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General and enable "Auto list members"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the version of your Visual Studio,as i am guessing you are using old version. i.e. 15.2 or lower.
Upgrade your visual studio and the issue will be resolved.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: I have Version 15.9.7

Comment: ok then please follow,  Tools>Options>Text Editor>Basic>Intellisense and check the checkboxes and then restart your visual studio

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if [this workaround](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/3258/view.html) helps.
 After that, right-click project to unload and reload the project.

2.Also, I'm wondering if you've installed any vs extension recently, I suggest you can start VS in [safe-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to check if it helps.

3.And for now the latest version of VS2017 is 15.9.12, I suggest you update your vs to help reslove the issue.(Or repair vs)
 Hope it helps:)