# VisualStudio 2012 keyboard shortcut (continue/for)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, editor

When I want to see where my `continue;` jumps I have to delete `;` and type it again (so something, let's call it Intellisense, will highlight `continue` and `for` or `while` line).

Same goes when I want to reformat something enclosed between `{` and `}` (in case formatting was not possible, because i wrote to example `double a =` inside and only after editing the rest could finish), I have to delete `}` (preferably the last one in the currently opened file) and type it again.

Question is:

- are there keybindings to simplify this? Like pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and then something?
- what are you guys doing, same as I deleting and retyping stuff to make things working?

P.S.: I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (and one with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense) and also did some Googling, no luck.

Comment: Sorry I'm not proving helpful. Perhaps try this, dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/visualstudio/…. Secondly, try this (CTRL+K)+(CTRL+D)

Comment: ctrl-k,ctrl-d works, also that tutorial with keybinding is useful. Thanks!