# Is there a Visual Studio shortcut to enumerate all properties in an object initializer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say I have a data model and it's got a bunch of properties. Is there a quick way to autocomplete the initialization like....:

```
var myobj = new MyObject
{
    A = ...,
    B = ...,
    .
    .
    Z = ...
};
```

So I can fill in the blanks on the properties but don't have to go on typing A...B...C... and so on?

Comment: @DaPosto I think that's what he's trying to do.  Resharper for example has this functionality, but I'm not sure if Visual Studio can do this or not.  It would be quite helpful.

Comment: are you talking about creating the class or just populating the properties for an existing class?

Comment: @MatthewWhited populating properties for the existing class, rather than having to type each one out in the initialization.

Comment: I don't know of anything built in to do that.  The good news is the number of possible options gets shorter as more properties are used.  You should be able to use the normal intellisense shortcuts.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense