# Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new with Visual Studio and I have been looking for keyboard shortcuts but I can't find the one that would show me the **doc** of a function.

Sometimes it shows it automatically but for other functions don't do it and when you start writing it dissapear so you can't read it again in case you need it.

In jupiter notebook you can do that by pressing in a function CONTROL + SHIFT but there is nothing in Visual Studio and I think it's very handy when you are new.

Please, could anyone help me.

Thank you

Comment: I think the hotkey you want is either `Ctrl+Space` for normal Intellisense, and/or `Ctrl+Shift+Space` for parameter Intellisense (e.g. to see what overloads are available in a method call which you've actually already filled in).  copied from JonSkeets answer in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145371/whats-the-default-intellisense-shortcut-in-vs2008

Comment: Hello thank you for your quick response but it is not what I am looking for. What you said it's for auto writing and Intellisense but I am only looking for getting the description of a built-in function.

For example, when writing "getattr()" I would like to see what it does, like a pop up text describing everything. Exactly the same description when you write "help(getattr)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Python latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with Python, but I believe the command you need to invoke is `Edit.QuickInfo`, to show docs for the symbol under the caret.

[image]

In this screenshot you can see it is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> on my machine. It may be different on yours. If you click on `Edit.QuickInfo` in the list of commands, it will show you what the shortcut is for your environment.